# Need help fetching an array from a prepared statment

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am new to using prepared statement with PHP. I am trying to get the value of "full_name"... So far I am stuck over here. Can anyone please help figure this out? Thanks!

```
if($db->connect_error){
    echo "Connection Error";
}

$id = 834;

$stmnt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM checkout_page where id = ?");
$stmnt->bind_param("i", $id);


if (!$stmnt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmnt->errno . ") " . $stmnt->error;
}


$row = $stmnt->fetch();
```

Comment: have you tried $full_name = $row['full_name'];?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `bind_result` to bind variables to the columns you want.  Then each time you call `fetch()`, those variables will be updated with the next row's values.  `fetch()` with mysqli does *not* return you the row/result.

This means you cannot use `SELECT *`.  You need to specify which fields you want.

```
if($db->connect_error){
    echo "Connection Error";
}

$id = 834;

$stmnt = $db->prepare("SELECT full_name FROM checkout_page where id = ?");
$stmnt->bind_param("i", $id);


if (!$stmnt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmnt->errno . ") " . $stmnt->error;
}

$stmnt->bind_result($full_name);
$stmnt->fetch();

echo $full_name;
```

Or, if you have the [mysqlnd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) driver installed, you can use `get_result()` to get a result set just like if you had ran a normal query, not a prepared statement.

```
if($db->connect_error){
    echo "Connection Error";
}

$id = 834;

$stmnt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM checkout_page where id = ?");
$stmnt->bind_param("i", $id);


if (!$stmnt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmnt->errno . ") " . $stmnt->error;
}

$result = $stmnt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

echo $row['full_name'];
```